# In EventSourcing, what's the accepted wisdom around subscriptions?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

As the title suggests. Currently I am using the `GetEventStore` backend for my events and that's working brilliantly. My confusion is with the subscriptions for keeping my Read store up to date.

Currently I'm creating a catch up subscription using the

```
EventStoreConnection.SubscribeToAllFrom(Position.Start, _subscriptionSettings, OnEventMaterialized, OnLiveProcessingStarted, OnSubscriptionDropped);
```

method. This works well and I have a way of caching all my particular event observers and they build my read model well.

However, what if I wanted to replay a particular aggregate's events? As it stands I need to start the subscription from the start again and let it all work through. The way I've done this to date is to store each observers current Stream Position, compare it with the subscription, and if greater, skip.

Is it better to have each observer have it's own subscription, that way only the one can be cleared? How do you know the Stream IDs in that case, do you need to persist every single stream id you create in order to re-subscribe at some later date?

Some code examples, or some reading, would be fantastic. I feel I'm missing the point with this final piece of the ES puzzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your general question: yes, each observer should maintain their own position in the queue.

> How do you know the Stream IDs in that case, do you need to persist every single stream id you create in order to re-subscribe at some later date?

Your stream names should be reproducible. The format I use is "events-{AggregateType}-{AggregateId}". I enable projections for GES and so the stream 
"$events-{AggregateType}" also exists. I can use this as the stream for one of my observers if needed.

Storing observer's configurations in a DB makes it easy to add a new one easily:

```
Name: All-Projections
StreamName: $events
Position: 1200 <-- This is updated by the observer as it reads
BufferSize: 100 <-- Number of records to read at a time

Name: Customers-Rebuild
StreamName: $events-CustomerAggregate
Position: 0 <-- This consumer has not run yet
BufferSize: 100
```

Then you can run your base consumer executable and pass the observer name as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for re-affirming my thinking - however, unless you store each aggregateid as well you won't know which streams to attach to if you "rebuilt".

Is this where the "Customers-Rebuild" projection comes from? That's giving you all your Ids?

Comment: Hi @JamesWoodley. With GetEventStore, if you run projections, it will create other meta-streams for you. Using category projections, you can get all events for all Customers, for example. This allows you to not have to care about the full list of Ids. https://eventstore.org/docs/projections/system-projections/index.html?tabs=tabid-5

Comment: @JamesWoodley No worries. I struggled with the same questions and am happy to share my findings.